# Why is my functional react component's state throwing TypeError: state is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, faunadb, netlify-function

I'm working on my first website in React, which is based off of a FaunaDB database. I'm using Netlify and Netlify functions to access my server-side code. When trying to to get all of the data from the database using react useEffect, useState, and useRef, I get TypeError: state is undefined. The results are set in state as an array of objects, so my initial value of state is an empty array. I tried converting to a class component, but I get the same response. I'm wondering if I shouldn't use array.map, but I already tried a for loop, and it doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't render anything.

Here is my code in the Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { getAll } from "../../fauna";

const AllResults = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    const isRendered = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getResults = async () => {
            try {
                if (!isRendered.current) {
                    const result = await getAll();
                    setState(result);
                    isRendered.current = true;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }

        getResults();
    }, [isRendered, setState]);

    console.log(state);

    const allResults = state.map((l) => {
        return <p key={ l.key } { ...l }></p>
    });
    
    return allResults;
}

export default AllResults;
```

Here is my getAll function:

```
export const getAll = () => {
    return fetch(
        "/.netlify/functions/read-all"
    )
    .then(
        (response) => {
            return response.json();
        }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        }
    );
}
```

and the function it is fetching:

```
const faunadb = require("faunadb");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve("../../../.env") });
const q = faunadb.query;
const db = new faunadb.Client({ secret: process.env.FAUNA_SERVER_KEY });

exports.handler = async (_event, _context, callback) => {
    console.log("Reading database...");
    try {
        const res = await db.query(
            q.Paginate(
                q.Match(
                    q.Index("all")
                )
            )
        );
        const all = res.data;
        console.log("Success! ${all.length} items found");

        const getAll = all.map(
            (ref) => {
                return q.Get(ref);
            }
        );
        const ret = await db.query(getAll);
        return callback(
            null,
            {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(ret.map((refs) => refs.data))
            }
        );
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        return callback(
            null,
            {
                statusCode: 400,
                body: JSON.stringify(err)
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This is my first time using React hooks, so I'm still learning. Please help!

Comment: It seems that `getAll` is resolving to `undefined`. I note that the `catch` block doesn't return anything - is the `console.error` call producing any output?

Comment: No, but I am seeing three logged things coming from the file, two empty arrays and `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe you should consider fallback to empty arrays in case of error to not break processing?

Comment: You should inspect the response from the fetch request; maybe it's not sending what you expect it to. I'm not familiar with netlify functions, but is it perhaps not automatically sending a `content-type: application/json` header? Maybe that's something your function needs to set so that the `response.json()` works properly.

Comment: I ran `console.log()` on the `response.json()`,  opened up the terminal, and found a 500 Internal server error, and the log said `Promise { "pending" } <state>:  "pending"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that all I needed to do was to make the `getAll` function asynchronous, so that the `await` would actually do something, and I knew it would work because `fetch` is a promise. It ended up looking like this:

```
export const getAll = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "/.netlify/functions/read-all"
      )
      
      const json = response.json();

      console.log(json);
      return json;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that your `getAll` method is not asynchronous, so the `await` doesn't do anything.  I would make that function async and see if that fixes your problem.

Also, second parameter of useEffect is an array of values that useEffect watches to see if it should run again, every time one of the values in that array changes the useEffect hook runs again.  Since you are doing an API call, I assume it should run once on the first render and then not again on subsequent renders.  In that case, I would leave the array blank so that it only runs once.  This is how the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method is replicated with hooks in a functional component.  I would reduce this hook slightly to look something more like this:

```
useEffect(() => {      
    getAll()
        .then(result => setState(result))
        .catch(e => console.log(e);
    }
}, []);
```